# Can auffordern (etc.) + an infinitive serve to introduce a stretch of indirect speech?

Tags: indirect-speech

Am I correct to think that the second and third sentences (in bold) of this quote (from [this Spiegel article](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/griechenland-alexis-tsipras-wirbt-fuer-nein-beim-referendum-a-1041624.html)) are indirect speech?

> Alexis Tsipras hat die Griechen in einer TV-Ansprache erneut dazu aufgefordert, bei dem Referendum am Sonntag mit Nein zu stimmen. **Anschließend will Griechenlands Ministerpräsident eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen. Es gehe bei der Abstimmung nicht um den Verbleib des Landes im Euro.**

If so, could you say (grammatically and idiomatically) *wolle* in place of *will* in the second sentence?

What is confusing me is that *will* is in the indicative and that *aufgefordert* + the infinitive is not the "classic" device to set off a stretch of indirect speech (something like *sagen* + a *dass* clause).

But the clear Konjunctiv I in the third sentence (*gehe*) and, above all, the context suggest that the newspaper is reporting what Tsipras said.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways we can mark quotes in a written communication. Direct speech in quoting marks, or indirect speech using subjunctive mood being the grammatically best defined choices:

> - Tsipras sagte, er wolle eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen. - *(indirect speech using subjunctive mood)*
> - Tsipras sagte: "Ich will eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen." - *(direct speech with quotes)*

However there are more possibilities to mark a quote either used for style or to shift the binding character of a quote:

> - Tsipras sagte, dass er eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen will. - *quote using a subordinate clause in indicative mood*
> - Tsipras sagte, dass er eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen wolle. - *quote using a double mark with subordinate clause **and** subjunctive mood*
> - Tsipras will eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen. - *quote in indicative mood **without** any mark*

The last example of an unmarked quote is what we can see in the source quoted in the question:

> - Anschließend will Griechenlands Ministerpräsident eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen.

The less we use marks the more we shift the binding character to reliability. Therefore it usually is not considered good style for a news report to use an unmarked indicative mood. But for stylistic reasons or to put emphasis on undoubted facts it may be used.

---

Further reading:

[IDS Mannheim: Kontexte der öffentlichen Kommunikation](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/sysgram.ansicht?v_typ=d&v_id=1004)

Comment: At first I thought this answer was diametrically opposed to Hubert Schölnast's, but I see that through the subtleties of the last paragraph the two answers may be reconciled. The "will" statement can only be deemed to be indirect speech if we read the reporter as having deviated from "good style" meaning (perhaps also) "strict grammar," which is what HS is trying to give me?

Comment: Strict grammar is put indirect speech in subjunctive mood. But the reality is different. There is more than grammar rules to writing, especially in magazines such as Spiegel.

Comment: Also, suppose that the second sentence said that the result of the referendum "wird geben" (and not "werde geben") Tsipras more leverage at the negotiations. I.e. it no longer concerns Tsipras's desire or intention. Would you (Takkat/Ingmar) still be inclined to see it as a "bad style" indirect speech (i.e. the same meaning as "werde geben")?  Or would you go with Schölnast's strict view and say that it ("wird geben") was the reporter's statement, not attributable to Tsipras?

Comment: In all cases the reporter quotes Tsipras but in the example given they obviously suggest that that there is no doubt that what he said will be done, hence they may have chosen the more direct binding character. But that's just hypothetical - we can't read the minds of the journalists involved.

Answer (score 1):

Ich antworte auf Deutsch, weil ich mich in meiner Muttersprache besser ausdrücken kann, und weil ich den Eindruck habe, dass du mich auch auf Deutsch gut verstehen wirst. Gerne übersetze ich meine Antwort ins Englische falls das notwendig sein sollte.

---

Nein, du irrst dich zumindest was den zweiten Satz betrifft. Die ersten beiden Sätze sind einfache Schilderungen von Sachverhalten, die von einem außenstehenden Beobachter (dem Journalisten) nüchtern und und sachlich vorgetragen werden. Was wir hier lesen sind Tatsachen, die der Journalist aus nicht näher angeführten Quellen erfahren hat, und nun dem Leser erzählt:

> Alexis Tsipras hat die Griechen in einer TV-Ansprache erneut dazu aufgefordert, bei dem Referendum am Sonntag mit Nein zu stimmen. Anschließend will Griechenlands Ministerpräsident eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen.

Der dritte Satz ist eine indirekte Rede, der die Einleitung fehlt. Mit Einleitung würde sie so lauten (Einleitung fett hervorgehoben):

> **Tsipras sagte,** es gehe bei der Abstimmung nicht um den Verbleib des Landes im Euro.

---

Doch schauen wir zurück zum zweiten Satz. Diesen Satz kann man natürlich - mit kleinen Änderungen - auch als indirekte Rede wiedergeben:

> **Tsipras sagte,** anschließend **wolle** *er* eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen.

Das ist aber im Originalsatz nicht der Fall. Der Journalist hat das zwar möglicherweise aus dem Munde von Tsipras gehört, hat es aber nicht als dessen Aussage, sondern als Tatsache wiedergegeben.

**Unterschiede**

> *(Tsipras sagte,)* anschließend **wolle** er eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen.

Hier wird wiedergegeben, dass Tsipras etwas über sich selbst behauptet. Es wird aber keine Aussage darüber gemacht, ob diese Aussage der Wahrheit entspricht. Es wäre möglich, dass Tsipras nur vorgibt diesen Plan zu haben, während er in Wirklichkeit etwas ganz anderes will. Fest steht allerdings, dass die Information aus Tsipras Mund stammt.

> Anschließend **will** er eine bessere Einigung mit den Gläubigern erzielen.

Hier wird der Plan des Ministerpräsidenten als wahre Tatsache wiedergegeben, die tatsächlich der Realität entspricht. Aus dem Satz lässt sich nicht herauslesen, woher diese Information kommt. Möglich ist, dass Tsipras das selbst gesagt hat. Es ist aber auch möglich, dass man die Gedanken von Tsipras mit einem Gehirn-Scanner gelesen hat, und auf diese Weise seine Absichten erfahren hat, oder es könnte auch sein, dass diese Nachricht aus einer Gruppe von Menschen kommt, die Tsipras so gut kennen, dass sie verlässlich Aussagen über seine Absichten machen können. Fest steht aber, dass Tsipras die geschilderte Absicht hat.

Comment: Thank you. The identification of "was fest steht" in each case was very helpful, as were the hypotheticals (brain scan etc.).